# I am trying to use geopandas to find polygons with are within 0.5m of each other using Dask. How do I multithread this operation?

Tags: python, pandas, gis, dask, geopandas

so the current code I have can find intersecting cells, but Dask will not run it in parallel - is there a reason why, and is there a simpler and faster way to do this?

The error message is located at the bottom; I tried using Dask Dataframes, but I need to perform operations on each row that affect every other row which precludes partitions.

```
@dask.delayed
def find_neighbours(tessellation, cell):
    # Get 'not disjoint' countries
    neighbours = tessellation[~tessellation.geometry.disjoint(cell.geometry)].uID.tolist()
    # Remove own uID of the cell from the list
    neighbours_list = [str(uID) for uID in neighbours if cell.uID != uID]
    return neighbours_list

# Constants
BATCH_SIZE = 64

out = []

# Function to process a batch
def process_batch(batch):
    # Compute the batch using Dask
    computed_batch = dask.compute(batch)
    # Update the original DataFrame with the results
    out.append(computed_batch)

# List to hold the current batch of delayed objects
current_batch = []

for index, cell in tessellation.iterrows():
    # Add the delayed task to the current batch
    result = find_neighbours(tessellation_scattered, cell)
    current_batch.append(result)

    # Check if the batch size is reached
    if len(current_batch) >= BATCH_SIZE:
        # Process the current batch
        batch_out = process_batch(current_batch)
        # Reset the batch
        current_batch = []

# Process any remaining tasks in the last batch
if current_batch:
    out.append(process_batch(current_batch))


Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-147' coro=<Server._handle_comm() done, defined at /home/virgilxw/miniconda3/envs/morph_model_v1_tess/lib/python3.11/site-packages/distributed/core.py:874> exception=AssertionError(<TaskState 'GeoDataFrame-29cf7ca7438cd2e0de98d630f312e41e' forgotten>)>
Traceback (most recent call last):

...

 File "/home/virgilxw/miniconda3/envs/morph_model_v1_tess/lib/python3.11/site-packages/distributed/scheduler.py", line 3375, in _task_to_msg
    assert ts.priority, ts
AssertionError: <TaskState 'GeoDataFrame-29cf7ca7438cd2e0de98d630f312e41e' forgotten>
```